# Problems generating tree diagram with hctreemap2

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(viridisLite)
library(forecast)
library(treemap)

data("Groceries", package = "arules")
dfitems <- tbl_df(Groceries@itemInfo)

set.seed(10)

dfitemsg <- dfitems %>%
  mutate(category = gsub(" ", "-", level1),
         subcategory = gsub(" ", "-", level2)) %>%
  group_by(category, subcategory) %>% 
  summarise(sales = n() ^ 3 ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  sample_n(31)


hctreemap2(group_vars = c("category","subcategory"),
           size_var = "sales")%>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
                            Pop: {point.value:,.0f}<br>
                            GNI: {point.colorValue:,.0f}")
```

the error is the following

`Error in hctreemap2(., group_vars = c("category", "subcategory"), size_var = "sales") :  Treemap data uses same label at multiple levels.`

I tried everything and it doesn't work out, could someone with experience explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your code, it also stated that the function was deprecated and to use `data_to_hierarchical`. Although, it's never quite that simple, right? I tried multiple ways to get `hctreemap2` to work, but wasn't able to discern that issue. From there I turned to the package recommended `data_to_hierarchical`. Now that worked without an issue--once I figured out the right `type`, which in hindsight seemed kind-of obvious.

That being said, this is what I've got:

```
data_to_hierarchical(data = dfitemsg,
                     group_vars = c(category,subcategory),
                     size_var = sales) %>% 
  hchart(type = "treemap") %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
                            Pop: {point.value:,.0f}<br>
                            GNI: {point.colorValue:,.0f}")
```

You didn't actually designate a color, so the GNI comes up blank.

[image]

Let me know if you run into any issues.

#### Based on your comment:

I have not found a way to change the color to density, which is what both `hctreemap2` and `treemap` appear to do. The function `data_to_heirarchical` codes the colors to the first grouping variable or the level 1 variable.

Inadvertently, I did figure out why the function `hctreemap2` would not work. It checks to see if any category labels are the same as a subcategory label. I didn't go through all of the data, but I know there is a `perfumery perfumery`. I don't understand what that's a hard stop. If that is a problem for this call, why wouldn't `data_to_heirchical` be looking for this issue, as well?

So, I changed the function. First, I called the function itself.

```
x = hctreemap2
```

Then I selected it from the environment pane. Alternatively, you can code `View(x)`.

This view is read-only, but it's easier to read than the console. I copied the function and assigned it to its original name with changes. I removed two pieces of the code, which changed nothing structurally speaking to how the chart is created.

I removed the first line of code in the function:

```
.Deprecated("data_to_hierarchical")
```

and this code (about a third of the way down)

```
if (data %>% select(!!!group_syms) %>% map(unique) %>% unlist() %>% 
        anyDuplicated()) {
        stop("Treemap data uses same label at multiple levels.")
    }
```

This left me to recreate the function with this code:

```
hctreemap2 <- function (data, group_vars, size_var, color_var = NULL, ...) 
{
  assertthat::assert_that(is.data.frame(data))
  assertthat::assert_that(is.character(group_vars))
  assertthat::assert_that(is.character(size_var))
  if (!is.null(color_var)) 
    assertthat::assert_that(is.character(color_var))
  group_syms <- rlang::syms(group_vars)
  size_sym <- rlang::sym(size_var)
  color_sym <- rlang::sym(ifelse(is.null(color_var), size_var, color_var))
  data <- data %>% mutate_at(group_vars, as.character)
  name_cell <- function(..., depth) paste0(list(...), 
                                           seq_len(depth), 
                                           collapse = "")
  data_at_depth <- function(depth) {
    data %>% 
      group_by(!!!group_syms) %>% 
      summarise(value = sum(!!size_sym), colorValue = sum(!!color_sym)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(name = !!group_syms[[depth]], level = depth) %>% 
      mutate_at(group_vars, as.character()) %>% {
        if (depth == 1) {
          mutate(., id = paste0(name, 1))
        }
        else {
          mutate(., 
                 parent = pmap_chr(list(!!!group_syms[seq_len(depth) - 1]), 
                                   name_cell, depth = depth - 1), 
                 id = paste0(parent, name, depth))
        }
      }
  }
  treemap_df <- seq_along(group_vars) %>% map(data_at_depth) %>% bind_rows()
  data_list <- treemap_df %>% highcharter::list_parse() %>% 
    purrr::map(~.[!is.na(.)])
  colorVals <- treemap_df %>% 
    filter(level == length(group_vars)) %>% pull(colorValue)
  highchart() %>% 
    hc_add_series(data = data_list, type = "treemap", 
                  allowDrillToNode = TRUE, ...) %>% 
    hc_colorAxis(min = min(colorVals), max = max(colorVals), enabled = TRUE)
}
```

Now your code, as originally written will work. You did not change the `highcharter` package by doing this. So if you think you'll use it in the future save the function code, as well. You will need the library `purrr`, since you already called `dplyr` (where most, if any conflicts occur), you could just call `tidyverse` (which calls several libraries at one time, including both `dplyr` and `purrr`).

This is what it will look like with `set.seed(10)`:

[image]

If you drill down on the largest block:

[image]

It looks odd to me, but I'm guessing that's what you were looking for to begin with.

Comment: Hello, it's perfect, but I would like to change the color to the gradient style.